# i want to assign value of count query to an integer variable

Tags: java, mysql

```
`String query = "select count(book_id) as book_id from library_books_details where book_id = ?";`
PreparedStatement psEnd = collegeCon.prepareStatement(query);

psEnd.setInt(1, bookId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = psEnd.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next()) {
        int count= rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("Count= " + count);
      } else {
        System.out.println("error: could not get the record counts");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

The flow of database access is

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String strColumn = rs.getString("....");
        int intColumn= rs.getInt("....");
    }
```